# Bridged network for LXC - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, lxc, network-bridge

I'd like to create a bridged network for three containers, with static IP addresses and connected to the internet through the ethernet card of the host machine.

For example, with the bridge named `letce0` and the virtual interfaces of the containers named `backchan0`, running the command `ifconfig` it should return something like

[image: for the host machine]
on the host machine

[image]
on the first container

[image]
on the second container

[image]
on the third container.

I know, if I'm not wrong, that I have to create before a bridged network through Netplan. In */etc/netplan* I have the file *01-network-manager-all.yaml* that contains:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

This is the situation of my interfaces:

```
andrea@andrea-System-Product-Name:~$ ifconfig
enp4s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether bc:ae:c5:32:64:b5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  

enp6s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 131.114.55.127  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 131.114.55.255
        inet6 fe80::519f:be0a:dcba:2f09  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2001:760:2c0c:701:1197:2c47:bb0e:4ee2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:760:2c0c:701:1520:ef2c:7e1b:4008  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether bc:ae:c5:32:64:b6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 139573  bytes 17012757 (17.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5793  bytes 862761 (862.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Loopback locale)
        RX packets 1148  bytes 100637 (100.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1148  bytes 100637 (100.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lxcbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.3.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 00:16:3e:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:ee:91:fe  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

where `enp6s0` is the ethernet card connected to the internet.

I have found several tutorial, but realized for previous version of Ubuntu (like this: https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/configure-bridged-networking-for-kvm-on-ubuntu-14-10.html).

Someone could help me?

Thank you very much!!

Andrea